# Is there a way to give a default view of xml on click of button which loads fragment in a container in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a frame layout which loads fragment on click of button which is all inside a fragment, but whenever i navigate to that fragment then it shows only those buttons and when i click on them then only the fragment shows up. I knew that all things are working correctly in this but i want to know is there a way to provide a default xml view for that fragment means before the click of any those button, the user is able to view an xml in that frame layout? 
P.S. : I am new to fragments so please answer calmly with detail. Thanks in advance.[image: This the fragment having two buttons in yellow and blue on which i want to show a default xml before clicking on these buttons by user]

The java code is:

```
public class AddHearingFragment extends Fragment {
Button b1,b2;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container != null) {
        container.removeAllViews();
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hearing,
            container, false);
b1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    b2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button7);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Myhearingfrag myf = new Myhearingfrag();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, myf);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Myteamhearingfrag myf = new Myteamhearingfrag();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, myf);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}}
```

And the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_marginTop="55dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:background="#FFBB00"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MY HEARING"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<Button
    android:background="#018AC1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MY TEAM HEARING"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try my answer @Annie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using **viewpager with tabs** then use below line in your onCreate() method

```
 //Creating our pager adapter
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

in Pager use:

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    //integer to count number of tabs
    int tabCount;

    //Constructor to the class 
    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        //Initializing tab count
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
    }

    //Overriding method getItem
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs 
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1(); // first fragment
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2(); // second fragment
                return tab2;
            case 2: 
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3(); // third fragment
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    //Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs 
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

try this link : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/

And If you are **not using viewpager** then use this link: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-way-to-create-tab-layout-in-android-without-viewpager

And according to your code. I have just modified your code. check this

```
public class AddHearingFragment extends Fragment {
Button b1,b2;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container != null) {
        container.removeAllViews();
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hearing,
            container, false);
b1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    b2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button7);

 Myhearingfrag myf = new Myhearingfrag();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, myf);
            transaction.commit();

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Myhearingfrag myf = new Myhearingfrag();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, myf);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Myteamhearingfrag myf = new Myteamhearingfrag();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, myf);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}}
```

Comment: i am just using two buttons with frame layout, so please suggest me how to add view of xml as a default before the user clicks on those two buttons and later it works on the click

Comment: MY HEARING and MY TEAM HEARING are buttons or tabs ?

Comment: Call your fragment in oncreate() of MainActivity.

Comment: @Annie use your following code 

Myhearingfrag myf = new Myhearingfrag();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, myf);
            transaction.commit();


 below these lines 

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hearing,
            container, false);
b1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    b2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button7);

Comment: My MainActivity is a navigation drawer, so is it ok to use this piece of code in that one?

Comment: @Annie use your following code Myhearingfrag myf = new Myhearingfrag(); FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, myf); transaction.commit(); below these lines 


View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hearing, container, false); b1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button8); b2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button7);

Comment: @Annie Glad to hear you found your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can make one fragment as a default view..
steps:

- Take a frame layout in xml and give an id to it.
- Create a Fragment class.And in oncreate inflate it's view.
- In Activity onCreate() ,Create an instance of Fragment class.
- After,Create an instance of Fragmentmanager and FragmentTransaction.
- Add your first fragment using instance of FragmentTransaction and commit it.

```
   FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
           ft.add("layout you added in activity xml",object of Fragment class);
           ft.commit();
```

Comment: where do i add this code ?? to a new fragment or to the old main fragment which is addhearing fragment as shown in my question?

Comment: You have to create your layout with two buttons in Activity layout. i.e My hearing and My team hearing. in your Activity onCreate() you need to add the above lines.Then your My Hearing Fragment shows up when you open that screen

Comment: When My Team heaering button is clicked simply add same lines in onclickListner of respective button.but instead of add you need to put replace.

Comment: thanks its a nice way but i already figured out another answer